# How to Preload an image in Android

Tags: android, titanium

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var view = Ti.UI.createView();

Titanium.UI.setBackgroundImage('images/logo.png');
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

Once this image is loaded, i need to navigate to next page in some seconds or when the application is loaded fully... how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a separate ImageView and add a listener for the "load" event, i.e.:

```
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({ url: 'images/logo.png' });
win.add(imageView);
imageView.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    // navigate here
});
```

Comment: How to navigate to the next page.... i mean page2.js.... can u show me the code for it... thanks

Comment: event listener load doesnt work with android, is there a replacement for that ?